# Chrome network tab not showing the full url on hover

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Earlier when i used to hover on a request in network tab, the tooltip used to show the full url, but i am not able to do that now. is there any way to enable it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open network panel settings (the second cog more to the right on your screenshot) and check/uncheck **"Use large request rows"**. After that the URL preview on hover started to magically work for me again (I had the same problem). If not, you can at least keep the large rows on as a last resort.